# Eclipse cant install Jaspersoft Studio 6.15

Tags: java, eclipse, jaspersoft-studio

I am not able to install Jaspersoft Studio 6.15 from the Eclipse Marketplace.

It goes to like 47% then it crashen with this error:

```
'Installing Software' has encountered a problem.
An error occured while collecting items to be installed
```

When I press details I get this log:

```
    An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=C__Dev_Programme_jee-2020-09_eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Artifact not found: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtend.lib,2.23.0.v20200831-0723.
Artifact not found: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtend.lib.macro,2.23.0.v20200831-0723.
Artifact not found: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext,2.23.0.v20200831-0730.
Artifact not found: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.builder,2.23.0.v20200831-0808.
Artifact not found: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.common.types,2.23.0.v20200831-0745.
Artifact not found: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.common.types.edit,2.23.0.v20200831-0808.
Artifact not found: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.common.types.ui,2.23.0.v20200831-0808.
Artifact not found: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.ide,2.23.0.v20200831-0730.
Artifact not found: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.smap,2.23.0.v20200831-0745.
Artifact not found: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.ui,2.23.0.v20200831-0808.
Artifact not found: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.ui.codetemplates,2.23.0.v20200831-0808.
Artifact not found: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.ui.codetemplates.ide,2.23.0.v20200831-0808.
Artifact not found: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.ui.codetemplates.ui,2.23.0.v20200831-0808.
Artifact not found: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.ui.shared,2.23.0.v20200831-0808.
Artifact not found: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.util,2.23.0.v20200831-0730.
```

This is my Eclipse IDE:

```
Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers (includes Incubating components)

Version: 2020-09 (4.17.0)
Build id: 20200910-1200
```

Anyone encountered similar problems?

Edit: Okay I just tried installing a different Marktplace Extension - eclipse FX and it installed without any problems..

Comment: It looks like your Eclipse installation is broken. Did you manually delete or edit some Eclipse related files or folders?

Comment: No I did not, my eclipse works normally i think. I installed some other extensions a few days ago without any problem tbh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I fixed it .. basically you search for the **Jaspersoft Studio** in the Eclipse Marketplace.

After that press the Arrow Button next to *"Installs"*. And then go to *'Open in external Browser'*.

Then you see a **Install Button** and you can drag that directly into your Eclipse Workspace.

After that agree to the Licenses and you are good to go!

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if I am too late but I seem to have got the same issue. I solved it by manually downloading the plugin from Sourceforge.

Go to the link [Source Forge JasperSoft update site](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jasperstudio/files/updatesite/)

This will take you to the updatesite page where you see a lot of versions. Make sure you click on 6.14 or lower and download the full-site.zip file.

Now go to Eclipse, Help > Install New software > Click on Add button > Click New button and then select the Zip file that you downloaded.

Now, once that's installed, restart Eclipse and go to Eclipse Marketplace, go to installed tab and search for Jaspersoft and click on the update button. Once Eclipse restarts, you should be good to go. Have any issues, just leave a comment.